# a question on notation for function spaces

Tags: notation

> If $X$ is some topological space, such
>   as the unit interval $[0,1]$, we can
>   consider the space of all continuous
>   functions from $X$ to $R$. This is a
>   vector subspace of $R^X$ since the sum
>   of any two continuous functions is
>   continuous and scalar multiplication
>   is continuous.

Please let me know the notation $R^X$ in the above example.

Comment: That notation just means the set of all functions $f: X \longrightarrow R$. Look at the first example in this Wikipedia entry for a [function space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space).

Comment: Rajesh, I think you should edit the question's title because it has nothing to do with continuous functions or vector spaces. You're just asking about the notation.

Comment: read the first chunk of cantor's "contributions to the founding of the theory of transfinite numbers"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the motivation for this notation (and thus also to remember it more easily), note that $|A^X|=|A|^{|X|}$. The analogy with exponentiation is even more direct if we use the set-theoretic construction of a natural number as the set of all its predecessors, e.g. $3=\{0,1,2\}$. In that case the sets denoted by $A^n$  (the $n$-fold Cartesian product of $A$, and $A^X$ with $X=n$ in the above sense) are isomorphic; in fact, under a set-theoretic definition of the Cartesian product, they are the same thing.

Comment: @Rajesh: Further motivation can be seen in the so-called *exponential law* $Z^{(Y \times X)} = (Z^{Y})^{X}$.

Answer (score 2):

This means the space of all functions from $X$ to $R$. Without regard for any structure. Set-theoretic ones.