# Formal language problem

Tags: computer-science, formal-systems

I’m new to formal language and searching for the solution for the following task:

$\Sigma$ is an alphabet with $\lvert \Sigma\rvert = 5$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

I’m searching for $\lvert \Sigma^k\rvert$.

Comment: This might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32247/a-question-on-notation-for-function-spaces/32251#32251

Comment: $\Sigma^k$ is the set of $k$-letter words on the letters of $\Sigma$. You want to know how many of those there are. Hence  @joriki's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you.

> $\Sigma^k$ is the set of k-letter words on the letters of Σ. You want to know how many of those there are.

So, therefor the answer is {amount_of_letters}$^5$ ?

For example:
{0,1} ... 2$^5$ words possible?
{a,b,c} ... 3$^5$ words possible?
and so on...

Comment: Yes. Think of a list $\Box\Box\Box\Box\Box$ and for each $\Box$ you can make $|\Sigma|$ distinct choices. So if you have $5$ boxes, there are $|\Sigma|^5$ possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

proposal for solution:

k's are elements of natural number, including zero.

->
$\Sigma$'s cardinality is five.
so 
$\Sigma^5$ = {01234} or {45678}

What I didn't understand: No word's parts are given, so how can I answer this question
without knowing, what is part of the language.

What I can say is, $\Sigma^5$ has five-digit words like {abcde} or {01234}...

However, i doubt, that this is the right solution...

---

Best regards,
jensen

Comment: (I´m working with jensen togehter in a team)